# Register with Azure Notification Hub using JavaScript on device

Tags: javascript, azure, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, azure-notificationhub

I am creating a PWA that I want to use Azure Notification Hub for Push Notifications

Reading the flow of registration for ANS, this document tells me that I must first obtain a PNS handle from the native service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management

> The device first retrieves the PNS handle from the PNS, then registers
>   with the notification hub directly

Using JavaScript, I am able to retrieve the handle which looks like this...

> {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/ewOnb-xuHQM:APA91bH7FWNQ9h9RKnOGHvxfPaF3OSr6FbnofFnLcE-bf6LtSYeNcDrCPN7DmwpcrKolUYQCw5qYI2UGZfaUkrGr555hfMkoCMFEchq6_yIUoPyyCxtQsT5Y6Cgc_c2jYD-HoQnvnWJV","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BPYcgtxUvSYDNYn6EVuu1BmIAz2vTU-TLdYb6pTAMOHTyJE1t8JLdBw1LLTljp5JMbnZF_Lk1ZoCV6nAJTUbDac","auth":"7cZDn_upNP_9HKO2NYhMbA"}}

Using the REST API for ANS, how do I pass this value (and which part) to register my device with the hub? And am I able to do this through JavaScript (not node.js) rather than backend?

Answer (score 0):

Push notification service is meant to receive notifications on mobile devices. PNS handle simply means the **Mobile Device Token** that you receieve from APNS in case of Apple devices, GCM for android devices. You use this Mobile device token as "Handle" in case of Azure Notification hubs.